# Porting to AIX 6.1 (ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol) with Xerces

Tags: c++, linux

## AIX 6.1

Porting an application from AIX 5.3 to AIX 6.1, Where it is building successfully in AIX 5.3. 
I am getting following errors while trying to build the same in 6.1.

1. Able to compile and create libraries from C and C++ source code
2. While trying to create a run time executable by using libraries the following error occurs

## Observations

Following errros are seems to be while trying call functions from the "libdocxml.a" library, which built successfully with xlC compiler earlier.

Compiler used: xlC_r, same compiler used for building all the libraries and application.

### NOTE:

Executables are building properly in 5.3 refering to this library.
But the same in 6.1 is giving above errors.

This library is related with xml parsers (xercesparser: XML4C and Xerces-C)

Please go through the end of the following error description. Actual errors are defined at the end.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
xlC_r -o acbbatch acbbatch.o acbbankserv.o acbbatchmain.o acbdinersclub.o acbmastercard.o acbmoneytransfer.o acbtype.o acbxcept.o acbcats.o -bloadmap:acbbatch.m /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libti.a /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libdocxml.a /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libintxml.a /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libdatalayer.a /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libsql.a /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libshared.a /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libstatdoc.a /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libfeeeng.a /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/lib32/libclntsh.a
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .bcopy
ld: 0711-344 See the loadmap file acbbatch.m for more information.
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOM_NamedNodeMap::DOM_NamedNodeMap()
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOMString::DOMString()
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOM_NamedNodeMap::operator=(const DOM_NamedNodeMap&)
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOMString::operator=(const DOMString&)
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOMString::DOMString(const char*)
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOMString::~DOMString()
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOMString::transcode() const
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .DOMString::length() const
.....
.....
.....
make: The error code from the last command is 8
```

FROM THE .M FILE
++++++++++++++++

```
(ld): halt 4
(ld): setopt tmplrename
(ld): setfflag 4
(ld): cdtors 0 all 0 s
(ld): savename acbbatch
(ld): filelist 27 1
(ld): i /lib/crt0.o
(ld): i /lib/crti.o
(ld): i acbbatch.o
(ld): i acbbankserv.o
(ld): i acbbatchmain.o
(ld): i acbtype.o
(ld): i acbxcept.o
(ld): i acbcats.o
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libti.a
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libdocxml.a
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libintxml.a
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libdatalayer.a
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libsql.a
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libshared.a
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libstatdoc.a
(ld): i /nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libfeeeng.a
(ld): i /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/lib32/libclntsh.a
(ld): lib /usr/vac/lib/libxlopt.a
(ld): lib /usr/vac/lib/libxlipa.a
(ld): lib /usr/vac/lib/libxl.a
(ld): lib /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libpthreads.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libm.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libc.a
LIBRARY: Shared object /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/lib32/libclntsh.ahttp://shr.o: 20863 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://shr_32.imp: 402
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://shr2_32.imp: 42
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://shr3_32.imp: 34
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://ansi_32.imp: 2441
LIBRARY: Shared object libC.ahttp://ansi_32.o: 2651 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://shr_64.imp: 0
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://shr2_64.imp: 0
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://shr3_64.imp: 0
LIBRARY: Symbols imported from import file /usr/vacpp/lib/libC.ahttp://ansi_64.imp: 0
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.ahttp://pse.o: 8 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.ahttp://dl.o: 4 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.ahttp://pty.o: 1 symbols imported.
FILELIST: Number of previously inserted files processed: 27
(ld): resolve
ld: 0711-228 WARNING: Duplicate symbols were found while resolving symbols.
The following duplicates were found:
Symbol Source-File(Object) OR Import-File{Shared-object}
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
.bcopy {/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/lib32/libclntsh.ahttp://shr.o}
** Duplicate ** moveeq.s(/usr/lib/libc.ahttp://moveeq.o)
RESOLVE: 1825 of 85325 symbols were kept.
RESOLVE: The return code is 4.
(ld): addgl /usr/lib/glink.o
ADDGL: Glink code added for 141 symbols.
(ld): er full
ld: 0711-318 ERROR: Undefined symbols were found.
The following symbols are in error:
Symbol Inpndx TY CL Source-File(Object-File) OR Import-File{Shared-object}
RLD: Address Section Rld-type Referencing Symbol
```

---

```
.__ct__16DOM_NamedNodeMapFv 518 ER PR docattributes.C(/nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libdocxml.ahttp://docattributes.o)
00000060 .text R_RBR 149 .__ct__13tDocAttributeFv
.__ct__9DOMStringFv 323 ER PR docerrorreporter.C(/nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libdocxml.ahttp://docerrorreporter.o)
000002a8 .text R_RBR 178 .fatalError__17tDocErrorReporterFRC17SAXParseException
000002bc .text R_RBR 178 .fatalError__17tDocErrorReporterFRC17SAXParseException
00000548 .text R_RBR 191 .error__17tDocErrorReporterFRC17SAXParseException
0000055c .text R_RBR 191 .error__17tDocErrorReporterFRC17SAXParseException
000008c8 .text R_RBR 222 .warning__17tDocErrorReporterFRC17SAXParseException
000008dc .text R_RBR 222 .warning__17tDocErrorReporterFRC17SAXParseException
.__ct__9DOMStringFv 520 ER PR docattributes.C(/nci5d10/prod/c/lib/libdocxml.ahttp://docattributes.o)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues before with Xerces and undefined symbols on AIX, and the issue was related to the symbol mangling options that can be specified to the xlc compiler.  By any chance was xerces built with the `-qnamemaning`flag (normally set to *v6* or *ansi*)?   If you run `dump` or `nm` over the xerces library without the symbols de-mangled, I'll willing to bet that them symbols won't match up with the mangled symbols in the error from the linker.